# XML Canonicalizer Problem

Tags: java, xml, canonicalization

I'm using the package `org.apache.xml.security.c14n`for the canonicalization of XMLs. I use the following code:

```
private String CanonicalizeXML(String XML) throws InvalidCanonicalizerException, CanonicalizationException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS);
    return new String(canon.canonicalize(XML.getBytes()));
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as I expected, since it doesn't delete any non-necessary white spaces between elements. Do I do something wrong?

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be your expectation which is incorrect:

You don't say which version of XML Canonicalization, but both 1.0 and 1.1 say:

> All whitespace in character content is
>   retained (excluding characters removed
>   during line feed normalization)

Comment: I want any version which would remove the spaces. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Is your xml document referencing a dtd or schema? Without one of those the parser has no way to know which whitespace is significant and so it has to preservere it.

Comment: Hmm... That explains a lot. I don't have a schema, but I will obviously have to create one. Or is there another way how to force it to delete whitespaces as they are irrelevant? Something like a very simple schema or something.

Answer (score 0):

The org.apache.xml.security.c14n does not remove whitespaces.

I resolved by setting setIgnoringBoundaryWhitespace = true on my SAXBuilder:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder ();
builder.setIgnoringBoundaryWhitespace(true);
org.jdom2.Document doc = builder.build(is);
DOMOutputter out = new DOMOutputter();
Document docW3 = out.output(doc);
```